# Canvas: Split circle into horizontal strips

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas, shapes

I'm trying to work out the best approach to split a circle shape in canvas into horizontal strips. I have an image as an example:

[image: Circle In Strips Example]

My first idea was to draw a set of rectangles and clip/crop it with a circle shape. But I need to animate/scale each individual strip. So really, I need to try and do it without clipping.

So I then thought about creating a curve/path, but the edges need to follow a perfect circle. Is there some basic math I could use to approach this?

I've done various bits of searching, however most resources point to pie charts, which is not what I'm after. I'll continue the search, but if you have an recommendations or resources I could look into I'd really appreciate it!

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using a gradient with zero-width changes from one color to the next?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I need each individual segment to be movable/independent. Unless we can do that with gradients? An example would be a rollover on a pie chart segment.

Answer (score 3):

Going along with the idea proposed by abiessu, here is an example of achieving that effect with an arc and gradient. I made the steps equal for the demo. This also shows it animating over time:

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s648zp85/)**

```
var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' ),
    ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' ),
    width = canvas.width = 400,
    height = canvas.height = 400,
    baseRadius = 100,
    rangeRadius = 50,
    colors = [
      '#2c7ba4',
      '#2a8598',
      '#47949e',
      '#2d8b79',
      '#549d82',
      '#5c9270',
      '#899277',
      '#cec2ac'
    ],
    tick = 0;

function loop() {
  requestAnimationFrame( loop );
  ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, width, height );
  var radius = baseRadius + Math.sin( tick / 50 ) * rangeRadius,
      spacing = ( height - radius * 2 ) / 2,
      gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient( 0, spacing, 0, height - spacing ),
      colorsLength = colors.length,
      i;

  for( i = 0; i < colorsLength; i++ ) {
    var color = colors[ i ];
    gradient.addColorStop( i / colorsLength, color );
    gradient.addColorStop( ( i + 1 ) / colorsLength, color );
  }

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc( width / 2, height / 2, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2 );
  ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
  ctx.fill();

  tick++;
}

document.body.appendChild( canvas );
loop();
```

Nice color palette, by the way!

[image: GIF Animation]

Comment: @Loktar Thanks! Stepping on your turf here ;) 17k+ rep? You're insane.

Comment: Thanks for your hard work. looks cool too :). However, I need the actual circle to be static and the parts of the circle to be moveable or segments? I guess an example would be when you roll over a pie chart segment?

Comment: @Patch5216 Ah, I see. Let me think about that for a little bit. Also, do you have a link to example of that kind of movement, like the pie chart? I think I know what you mean, just want to be sure though.

Comment: hi @jackrugile, thanks for replying! there is a pie chart at top of the page here: https://developers.google.com/chart/ and some other examples here: http://www.chartjs.org/ . If you hover/rollover you'll see what I mean. They all work well, but i'm just unsure how to split it horizontally or vertically :S

Comment: Ah I see, so you want it to work like those pie charts, where each section can be worked with independently, but your would just be horizontal strips instead of built from center like a normal pie chart. That's tough, will ponder ;)